# Loading Textures in Background Cocos2d Objective C loading CCScene

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am allocating a few CCScene subclasses, but when I do this, it takes more than 10 seconds. What I am trying to achieve is to perform a small CCAmimation, such as a loading logo glowing. My question is: how do I load those CCScene subclasses in the background and perform this animation.

I am able to perform these things separately, but I want to do them together.

Comment: Fixed:-
I have achieved this by using NSOperationQueue.
Did the loading and animation in parts simultaneously.